# Duda sobre juego en c++

Tags: c++

soy nuevo en este foro y tengo algunas dudas respecto a mi trabajo final de programación, tengo que realizar el juego Fishing Derby de atari en c++, ya tengo el movimiento de los peces y el tiburon pero no es aleatorio como me lo piden y tambien me falta que mi caña detecte a los peces y los pesque. 
Si me ayudan se los agradecería demasiado,ya van varios dias que me quedo hasta tarde intentando terminar mi juego...
Les dejo mi codigo...
Ignoren el menu que aun estoy trabajando en eso.
Si encuentran algun error me avisan por favor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
void Creditos(int *Opcion) {

    cout << "Creditos" << endl;
}
void Rules(int *Opcion) {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Instrucciones" << endl;
}
void Game(int *Opcion) {


}
void Menu(int *Opcion) {
    menuuu:
    Console::SetWindowSize(100, 44);
Opcion:
    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(7);
    Console::SetCursorPosition(10, 2); cout << "______ _____ _____ _   _ _____ _   _ _____   ______ ___________________   __";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(10, 3); cout << "|  ___|_   _/  ___| | | |_   _| \\ | |  __ \\  |  _  \\  ___| ___ \\ ___ \\ \\ / /";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(10, 4); cout << "| |_    | | \\ `--.| |_| | | | |  \\| | |  \\/  | | | | |__ | |_/ / |_/ /\\ V / ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(10, 5); cout << "|  _|   | |  `--. \\  _  | | | | . ` | | __   | | | |  __||    /| ___ \\ \\ /  ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(10, 6); cout << "| |    _| |_/\\__/ / | | |_| |_| |\\  | |_\\ \\  | |/ /| |___| |\\ \\| |_/ / | |  ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(10, 7); cout << "|_|    \\___/\\____/\\_| |_/\\___/\\_| \\_/\\____/  |___/ \\____/\\_| \\_\\____/  \\_/  ";

    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(7);
    Console::SetCursorPosition(18, 9); cout << " ____ ____ ____ _________ ____ ____ ____ ____ ____ ____ ____ ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(18, 10); cout << "||C |||+ |||+ |||       |||E |||d |||I |||T |||I |||O |||N ||";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(18, 11); cout << "||__|||__|||__|||_______|||__|||__|||__|||__|||__|||__|||__||";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(18, 12); cout << "|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/_______\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|/__\\|";

    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(6);
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 13); cout << " _             _                        ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 14); cout << "/ |           | |_   _  __ _  __ _ _ __";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 15); cout << "| |        _  | | | | |/ _` |/ _` | '__|  ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 16); cout << "| |_      | |_| | |_| | (_| | (_| | |    ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 17); cout << "|_(_)      \\___/ \\__,_|\\__, |\\__,_|_|     ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 18); cout << "                       |___/            ";

    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 19); cout << " ____      ___           _                       _                        ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 20); cout << "|___ \\    |_ _|_ __  ___| |_ _ __ _   _  ___ ___(_) ___  _ __   ___  ___  ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 21); cout << "  __) |    | || '_ \\/ __| __| '__| | | |/ __/ __| |/ _ \\| '_ \\ / _ \\/ __| ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 22); cout << " / __/ _   | || | | \\__ \\ |_| |  | |_| | (_| (__| | (_) | | | |  __/\\__ \\ ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 23); cout << "|_____(_) |___|_| |_|___/\\__|_|   \\__,_|\\___\\___|_|\\___/|_| |_|\\___||___/ EN PROCESO";

    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 24); cout << " _____     ____              _ _ _                  ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 25); cout << "|___ /    / ___|_ __ ___  __| (_) |_ ___  ___       ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 26); cout << "  |_ \\   | |   | '__/ _ \\/ _` | | __/ _ \\/ __|   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 27); cout << " ___) |  | |___| | |  __/ (_| | | || (_) \\__ \\    ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 28); cout << "|____(_)  \\____|_|  \\___|\\__,_|_|\\__\\___/|___/ EN PROCESO";

    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 29); cout << " _  _       ____        _ _         ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 30); cout << "| || |     / ___|  __ _| (_)_ __    ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 31); cout << "| || |_    \\___ \\ / _` | | | '__|   ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 32); cout << "|__   _|    ___) | (_| | | | |      ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 33); cout << "   |_|(_)  |____/ \\__,_|_|_|_|      ";
    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(15);

    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 36); cout << "INGRESE LA OPCION QUE DESEE!!" << endl;
    Console::SetCursorPosition(3, 37); cout << "-"; cin >> *Opcion;
    if (*Opcion == 1) {
        system("cls");
        Game(Opcion);
    }
    if (*Opcion == 2) {
        system("cls");
        Rules(Opcion);
    }
    if (*Opcion == 3) {
        system("cls");
        Creditos(Opcion);
    }
    if (*Opcion == 4) {

        system("cls");


    }
    if (*Opcion < 1 || *Opcion > 4) {
        system("cls");
        goto Opcion;
    }
}
void Borrar_Cuadrado(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x) {
    for (int F = 1; F <= 5; F = F + 1) {
        for (int C = 1; C <= 15; C = C + 1) {
            Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 5);
            cout << " ";
            *X = *X + 1;
        }
        *Y = *Y + 1;
        *X = *Inicio_x;
    }
}
void MoverCaña(int *XCaña, int *YCaña) {

}
void Imprimir_CuadradoT2(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *X1) {
    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(15);
    *X1 = 0;
    for (int I = 0; I <= 5; I = I + 1) {
        *X1 = *X1 + 8;
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 10); cout << "                        .`)                      ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 11); cout << "                      .` /                       ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 12); cout << "            _.---.._.`  (                        ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 13); cout << "           (  o          `---...__       .`/      ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 14); cout << "            ',___    ,            '--,_.` /      ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 15); cout << "              '-,_   (  /           _.-, (       ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 16); cout << "                  ''--\\/ _____..--``    ',\\    ";
    }
}
void Imprimir_CuadradoT1(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *X1) {
    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(15);
    *X1 = 0;
    for (int I = 0; I <= 5; I = I + 1) {
        *X1 = *X1 + 8;
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 10); cout << "                           (`.                  ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 11); cout << "                            \\ `.               ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 12); cout << "                             )  `._..---._      ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 13); cout << "           \\`.       __...---`         o  )    ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 14); cout << "            \\ `._,--'           ,    ___,'     ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 15); cout << "             ) ,-._          \\  )   _,-'       ";
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, 16); cout << "            /,'    ``--.._____\\/--''           ";


    }
}
void Imprimir_Cuadrado(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *X1) {
    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(15);
    *X1 = 0;
    for (int I = 0; I <= 5; I = I + 1) {
        *X1 = *X1 + 1;
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, Inicio_y[I]);     cout << "           <" << char(167) << ")))><     "; // x 23 12

    }
}
void Imprimir_Cuadrado1(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *X1) {
    Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(15);
    *X1 = 0;
    for (int I = 0; I <= 5; I = I + 1) {
        *X1 = *X1 + 8;
        Console::SetCursorPosition(*X, Inicio_y[I]);     cout << "         ><(((" << char(167) << ">   ";


    }
}
void Mover_izquierda(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *borde_izquierdo, int *X1)
{
    for (int I = 0; I <= 5; I = I + 1) {
        *X = *Inicio_x; // Columnas
        *Y = Inicio_y[I]; // Filas
        Borrar_Cuadrado(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x);
        if (*Inicio_x > *borde_izquierdo) {
            *Inicio_x = *Inicio_x - 1;
        }
        *X = *Inicio_x; // Columnas
        *Y = Inicio_y[I]; // Filas
        Imprimir_Cuadrado(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);

        Imprimir_CuadradoT2(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);
    }
}
void Mover_derecha(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *borde_derecho, int *X1)
{
    for (int I = 0; I <= 5; I = I + 1) {
        *X = *Inicio_x; // Columnas
        *Y = Inicio_y[I]; // Filas.
        Borrar_Cuadrado(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x);
        if (*Inicio_x + *Lado < 100) {
            *Inicio_x = *Inicio_x + 1;
        }
        *X = *Inicio_x; // Columnas
        *Y = Inicio_y[I]; // Filas.
        Imprimir_Cuadrado1(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);
    }
}
void Mover_derecha1(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *borde_derecho, int *X1)
{
    for (int I = 0; I <= 5; I = I + 1) {
        *X = *Inicio_x; // Columnas
        *Y = Inicio_y[I]; // Filas.
        Borrar_Cuadrado(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x);
        if (*Inicio_x + *Lado < 80) {
            *Inicio_x = *Inicio_x + 1;
        }
        *X = *Inicio_x; // Columnas
        *Y = Inicio_y[I]; // Filas.
        Imprimir_CuadradoT1(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);
    }
}
void Tiburon(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *XCaña, int *YCaña, int *borde_izquierdo, int *borde_derecho, int *Direccion, int *X1) {
    Borrar_Cuadrado(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x);
    Imprimir_CuadradoT2(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);
    Imprimir_CuadradoT1(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);
    Mover_izquierda(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, borde_izquierdo, X1);
    Mover_derecha1(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, borde_derecho, X1);

}
void Pez(int *X, int *Y, int *Lado, int *Inicio_x, int *Inicio_y, int *XCaña, int *YCaña, int *borde_izquierdo, int *borde_derecho, int *Direccion, int *X1)
{

    Borrar_Cuadrado(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x);
    Imprimir_Cuadrado(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);
    Imprimir_Cuadrado1(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, X1);
    Mover_izquierda(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, borde_izquierdo, X1);
    Mover_derecha(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, borde_derecho, X1);


}
void Vidas(char *Vida) {
    Console::SetCursorPosition(107, 1); cout << "VIDAS " << char(3) << char(3) << char(3) << endl;


}
void Puntaje(int *Puntos) {
    Console::SetCursorPosition(93, 1); cout << "PUNTAJE " << " 000 " << endl;
}
void Tiempo(int *Time) { //300000


}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int *X = new int;                   int *Y = new int;
    int *Lado = new int;                int *Inicio_x = new int;
    int *Inicio_y = new int[5];         int *borde_derecho = new int;
    int *borde_izquierdo = new int;     int *borde_inferior = new int;
    int *Direccion = new int;
    char *Vida = new char;   int *Puntos = new int; int *Time = new int;
    *borde_derecho = 100; *borde_izquierdo = 1; *borde_inferior = 44; *Inicio_x = 0; Inicio_y[0] = 18; *Lado = 15;   *Direccion = 1;
    Inicio_y[1] = 21; Inicio_y[2] = 26; Inicio_y[3] = 30; Inicio_y[4] = 36; Inicio_y[5] = 41;
    int *XCaña = new int; *XCaña = 22;  int *YCaña = new int; *YCaña = 8;
    *X = *Inicio_x; // Columnas
    *Y = *Inicio_y; // Filas.
    int *BD = new int[5];
    int *X1 = new int[5];
    int *Opcion = new int;
    Menu(Opcion);
    cout << "" << endl;
    if (*Opcion == 3) {
        system("cls");
        system("pause");
    }
    if (*Opcion == 4)
    {
        system("cls");

        goto salir;
    }
    Console::SetWindowSize(130, 44);
    Console::CursorVisible = false;
    Pez(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, XCaña, YCaña, borde_derecho, borde_izquierdo, Direccion, X1);
    Tiburon(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, XCaña, YCaña, borde_derecho, borde_izquierdo, Direccion, X1);
    Puntaje(Puntos);
    Vidas(Vida);
    Tiempo(Time);
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 1); cout << " |__          /`-._     ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 2); cout << " |_`\\_      /     `-._ ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 3); cout << " |/^}__..-,@          |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 4); cout << " |(____.-'            |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 5); cout << " |  \\ / `\\           | ";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 6); cout << " |\\ /' /\\_\\_          |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 7); cout << " | \\'--' `---`        |";
    Console::SetCursorPosition(1, 8); cout << " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\\_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";

    /*-*/
    while (true)
    {

        //MoverCaña(XCaña, YCaña);
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;

        Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña); //21 7
        Console::WriteLine("|");
        if (_kbhit())
        {

            keyinfo = Console::ReadKey();
            keyinfo = Console::ReadKey();

            /*if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey::Enter) {
            Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(4);

            Console::SetCursorPosition(70, 1); cout << "VIDAS " << char(3) << char(3);
            }*/
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey::M)
            {
                system("cls");
                Menu(Opcion);
                if (*Opcion == 3) {
                    system("cls");
                    system("pause");
                }
                if (*Opcion == 4)
                {
                    system("cls");

                    goto salir;
                }
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey::UpArrow)
            {

                Console::ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor(15);

                *YCaña = *YCaña - 1;
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña + 1);
                Console::WriteLine("o");
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña + 1);
                Console::WriteLine("o");
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña + 2);
                Console::WriteLine(" ");
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña + 2);
                Console::WriteLine(" ");
                /*break;*/
            }
            if (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey::DownArrow)
            {

                *YCaña = *YCaña + 1;
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña);
                Console::WriteLine("|");
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña + 1);
                Console::WriteLine("o");
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña - 1);
                Console::WriteLine("|");
                Console::SetCursorPosition(*XCaña, *YCaña + 1);
                Console::WriteLine("o");

            }
            /*if (*YCaña == 18 && *X == 12) {
            system("pause");
            }*/
        }
        if (*Direccion == 1)
        {
            Mover_derecha(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, borde_derecho, X1);
            Mover_derecha1(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, borde_derecho, X1);

        }
        if (*Direccion == 2)
        {
            Mover_izquierda(X, Y, Lado, Inicio_x, Inicio_y, borde_izquierdo, X1);
        }
        if (*Lado + *Inicio_x == 80) { *Direccion = 2; }  if (*Lado + *Inicio_x == 100) { *Direccion = 2; }
        if (*Inicio_x == *borde_izquierdo) { *Direccion = 1; }
        //TIEMPO
        /*for (int t = 0; t < 1000; t++)
        {
        for (int i = 300; i >= t; i--) {
        Console::SetCursorPosition(118, 1);cout << "TIEMPO " << i;
        _sleep(1000);
        }
        }*/
        _sleep(50);
    }
salir:
    return 0;
}
```

---

Mi problema es que no se como realizar que los peces aparezcan aleatoriamente y que la caña los pesque(osea detectar la colision)

Comment: ¡Las preguntas sobre hacer juegos son muy interesantes! :D pero las preguntas de "tengo un problema ¿Cómo lo soluciono?" sin explicar exactamente cuál es el problema no son bien recibidas. Por favor, explica cuál es exactamente tu problema.